# The U+0126 problem

Tags: unicode

See, I wanted to type Ħ but I couldn't find any command so please can you find a command except `Ħ` as a Unicode character. I'm also using XeLaTeX, but the viewers aren't so please help me and those persons.

Comment: what do you mean by "viewers aren't` ? peopl reading your pdf do not need xetex. xetex will show that character if you specify a suitable font that has it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This is an IPA symbol. How do I know? I googled it, so you will need a font that contains it.

Comment: @yannisl It's a letter in the Maltese alphabet.

Comment: @egreg Thanks I see the difference in the wiki.

Comment: The Unicode character is in Latin Modern Roman and Libertinus Serif fonts, and some others. Not to be confused with Planck's contstant/2pi, which is at another code point. Also: Although many TeX fonts have this character, it is possible that whatever software you use for typing, chooses a font that does not have this symbol. So, be sure that you choose a suitable font for typing.

Answer (score 6):

You  do not need a command

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Ħ

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

with xelatex.

Wth pdflatex you get

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character Ħ (U+0126)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 Ħ
      
? h
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter 
?
```

But as the help text says you can declare the character

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0126}{H\llap{\rule[1ex]{.8em}{.04em}}}
\fi

\begin{document}

Ħ

\end{document}
```

with pdflatex produces

[image]

You can of course adjust the bar position as required.

Or with pdftex you may prefer the `B{H}` from the fc font designed for African languages using Latin script

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1,T4]{fontenc}
\ifdefined\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0126}{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\B{H}}}
\begin{document}

Ħ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: The Maltese Ħ is very different from the `\B{H}` character (not to mention that T4 fonts are only available as bitmap.

Comment: @egreg sure but I offered a bar rule first, which isn't substantially different to using a bar glyph

Answer (score 6):

For XeLaTeX just use the character. For `pdflatex` you need to define the characters by imposing a bar to H and h.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0126}{\malteseH}%
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0127}{\malteseh}%
\newcommand{\malteseH}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \dimen0=\fpeval{(\the\fontdimen1\font)/(1pt)}\fontcharwd\font`H
    \hspace{0.05\fontcharwd\font`H}%
    \hspace{\dimen0}%
    \rule[1.15ex]{\dimeval{0.9\fontcharwd\font`H-0.5\dimen0}}{0.035em}%
  }H%
}
\newcommand{\malteseh}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \dimen0=\fpeval{(\the\fontdimen1\font)/(1pt)}\fontcharwd\font`h
    \hspace{0.05\fontcharwd\font`h}%
    \hspace{\dimen0}%
    \rule[1.2ex]{0.45\fontcharwd\font`h}{0.035em}%
  }h%
}

\begin{document}

Ħ ħ \textbf{Ħ ħ} \textit{Ħ ħ}

GĦ għ

GH gh

\end{document}
```

[image]